# Conditional SQL Join from several tables

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that are connected. I need to make a single SQL selection and I know I need to use join of some form but not quite how. I only want the objectID to be selected if the session for userID has access to that object´s area (user gets access if their company has access to the area) The tables I have are:

```
+----------+--------+ Objects
| objectID | areaID |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      2 |
|        2 |      2 |
|        3 |      3 |
+----------+--------+
+-----------+--------+ Users
| companyID | userID |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      1 |
|         1 |      2 |
|         1 |      3 |
+-----------+--------+
+-----------+--------+ Access
| companyID | areaID |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      1 |
|         1 |      2 |
|         1 |      3 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Selected UserID and corresponding areaIDs in `inner query` using companyID. Then using this, selected distinct ObjectID from Objects table using inner join again with table formed through `inner query`

Try this query:-

```
Select distinct a.objectID 
from
Objects a
inner join
(
Select a.*,b.areaID
from
Users a
inner join
Access b
on a.companyID=b.companyID
) b
on a.areaID=b.areaID
Where b.UserID= 1;
```

Comment: But where would i put the session variable for the active user´s userID?

Comment: Just put a 'Where condition' with userID.I have updated my query. Used userID 1 as example. you can change that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it seems like two `INNER JOIN` functions would get the results you're looking for:

```
WITH ONE AS (
    SELECT a.companyID, a.userID, b.areaID
    FROM Users a
    INNER JOIN Access b
    ON a.companyID = b.companyID
    )

SELECT a.companyID, a.userID, a.areaID, b.objectID
FROM ONE a
INNER JOIN Objects b
ON a.areaID = b.areaID;
```

**EDIT: Reply to comment**

If you want to limit the results to a specific userID value, you'll need a `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH ONE AS (
    SELECT a.companyID, a.userID, b.areaID
    FROM Users a
    INNER JOIN Access b
    ON a.companyID = b.companyID
    )

SELECT a.companyID, a.userID, a.areaID, b.objectID
FROM ONE a
INNER JOIN Objects b
ON a.areaID = b.areaID
WHERE a.userID = ${specific_user_id};
```

Comment: But where would i put the session variable for the active user´s userID?

Comment: I just made an edit showing how you'd add a `WHERE` clause to do that.